# Set a global variable with a local variable

Tags: ios, xcode, global, host

I got this global variable

## define AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME @"(hostname).mob"

And I want to change the hostname with a segmented control variable, that defines different regions (Europe-USA-Australia)

Thanks

Sorry for my ignorance, im a begginer

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Pre-Processor macros after compile time.  You are going to need to set a global NSString for what you want accomplished.

.h

```
extern NSString *AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME;

@interface SomeClass
{

}
@end
```

.m

```
NSString *AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME;
@implementation SomeClass

-(id)init
{
    //Do the if(self) stuff
    {
        AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME = @"(hostname).mob";
    }
}

-(void)FunctionToChangeStuff:(NSString*)somethingElse
{
    AN_MOBILE_HOSTNAME = somethingElse;
}
@end
```

Or you could make the object a class variable if you have a singleton class that your program knows about.